# Python split function and array

Tags: python, arrays, class, split, initialization

Write a class Extract with passing your full name as one of the attributes in init method.
Then use init method variables and split function to split the  first and last name and store them in arrays.

so far this is what I have gotten:

```
class Fullname:
  def __init__(self, firstname,lastname):
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname

  def Fullname(self):
    return('{} {}'.format(self.firstname, self.lastname))
fullname = Fullname("Ashley", "Olsen")

print(fullname.Fullname())
```

My output is:

```
Ashley Olsen
```

The expected output I am trying to get is:

```
Ashley Olsen
Ashley
Olsen
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems directions are different from your implementation, namely: 1) class name should be Extract ("Write a class Extract"), 2) _init_should take full name ("full name as one of the attributes in init"), 3) array to to split of fullname ("split function to split the first and last name".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use \n to separate the rows.

```
class Fullname:
  def __init__(self, firstname,lastname):
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname

  def Fullname(self):
    return('{} {}'.format(self.firstname, self.lastname) + '\n' + self.firstname + '\n' + self.lastname)

fullname = Fullname("Ashley", "Olsen")
print(fullname.Fullname())
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I just tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answering! I figured out the answer.

> ```
> class Extract:
>      def __init__(self, fullname):
>      self.fullname = fullname
>      divided_name = fullname.split(" ")
>      self.firstname = divided_name[0]
>      self.lastname = divided_name[-1]
> ```

```
 person = Extract("Ashley Olsen")

 print(person.fullname)
 print(person.firstname)
 print(person.lastname)

 Output: 
 Ashley Olsen
 Ashley
 Olsen
```

> 